# how to execute a react component from html

Tags: reactjs, erb

I am starting to build a react component to learn how. I want to embed it into an existing html page (well, erb anyway) but I am not sure how to get it to execute.

refreshing the page does not do anything or render what is in the react component. Console logs do not appear either, so I am guessing that it is not executing.

```
// in main_control.js
var MainControl = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Something something Dark Side</div>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MainControl />,
  document.getElementById('main_control')
);

// in the html file
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src='/components/main_control.js' type='text/babel'>     
</script>
</head>


<h3>control for <%= @site.site_name %> </h3>


<div id="main_control"></div>
```

~

The only thing that shows up is what is in the  tag

Answer (score 1):

You were close, here is how you create a stateless component :

```js
const MainControl = () => {
    return <div>Something something Dark Side</div>
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <MainControl />,
  document.getElementById('main_control')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<h3>control for <%= @site.site_name %> </h3>
<div id="main_control"></div>
```

And here is how you create a statefull one :

```js
class MainControl extends React.Component{
  render(){
      return <div>Something something Dark Side</div>
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <MainControl />,
  document.getElementById('main_control')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<h3>control for <%= @site.site_name %> </h3>
<div id="main_control"></div>
```

If you want to generate your site name dynamically using React :

```js
const MainControl = ({ siteName }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{siteName}</h3>
        <div>Something something Dark Side</div>
      </div>
    )
    
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <MainControl siteName='My website'/>,
  document.getElementById('main_control')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.1.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.1.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_control"></div>
```